# Replace string with many special character with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I cant figure out how to replace this string:

```
RewriteRule .*\/Custom\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/expose_(short|long)\.php(.*)  https://111.111.11.11/markt3/Custom/expose.php?customer=$1&variant=$2$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

with this:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\/Custom\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/expose_(short|long)\.perl $1/Custom/expose.perl?kunde=$2&variant=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Can I do this with sed? If yes -> how can do this with sed?
All the special charakter making it quite difficult

Thanks

Comment: You can but **what is you pattern?**

Comment: Take the tour (http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should demonstrate that you did some experimenting yourself. And you might find the part of the sed documentation (or tutorial) interesting which talks about extended regexes `-E` and "escaping".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)